# Character Spacing in SSRS 2014

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, crystal-reports

I am trying to get character spacing between characters. I am familiar with Crystal Report has the feature to do under font format properties. However, unable to find any solution in SSRS.

I am trying to achieve 10 digits in an inch. I am using OCR A Extended with size 12pt, but it doesn't give desire results.

Crystal Report Feature:

[Crystal Report Feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgLWQ.png)

I also tried the code to get, but SPACE function doesn't support decimals.

```
Public Function CompletePrefAddress (ByVal dbField1 As String, intSpacesBetween As Decimal) As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim strOriginal As String
Dim strNew As String
strOriginal = dbField1 
strNew = ""
For i = 1 To Len(strOriginal)
  strNew = strNew & Space(intSpacesBetween) & Mid(strOriginal, i, 1)
Next i
    Return strNew 
End Function
```

Comment: It depends on the Font Type you are using.  You can have Fixed Spaced or Fixed Width.

Comment: I am using OCR A Extended, but still need space to make 10 digits in an inch

Comment: It is fixed pitch.  So characters are different widths and distance between characters are fixed.  So if you have a wide character like 'W' you will get less characters per inch then a small charcter 'i'.

Answer (score 0):

Every font has its own character spacing. However, to achieve 10th in an inch, I had to split the whole field into a single character using Mid(,n,1) and change the location to 7.2pt. so for each character, it increments with 7.2pt in the left location and the formula goes with the addition of 1.